# R: add character vector to data.frame row

Tags: r, vector

I have a data frame (DF) look like this:

```
a   e   1   4
d   f   2   5
c   g   3   6
```

I need to insert a vector, c("g, "H", 7, 8), to the first row of DF, so that it look like this

```
g   H   7   8
a   e   1   4
d   f   2   5
c   g   3   6
```

But when I use this command line `InsertRow(DF, vector, RowNum=1)', it will return a warning message and the first row of DF ended up like this

Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "g") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "H") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated`

```
<NA> <NA>   7   8
```

Can anyone show me how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: convert the factor columns to character and try `rbind(data.frame(V1='g', V2='H', V3=7, V4=8), DF)` if `V1, V2, . are the column names

Comment: Thanks. just curious, what if I have a long vector and a data.frame with many columns instead. Is there a way to bind them without typing out "V1=...". Thanks.

Comment: It you have a dataset with mixed class as shown in the example, the problem with the vector is that it can hold only one type, So, when you rbind, the output dataframe will be all character columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the initial dataset ('DF') have some 'factor' columns as in the post.  Before `rbind` the vector ('v'), change the 'factor' columns to 'character'.  For that create a logical index ('indx') of the factor columns, loop through the `factor` columns and convert to character (`lapply(DF[indx],..)`).  `rbind` the vector with the dataset and convert the column classes with `type.convert`.

```
indx <- sapply(DF, is.factor)
DF[indx] <- lapply(DF[indx], as.character)
DF1 <- rbind(v, DF)
DF1[] <- lapply(DF1, type.convert)
DF1
#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  g  H  7  8
#2  a  e  1  4
#3  d  f  2  5
#4  c  g  3  6

str(DF1)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ V1: Factor w/ 4 levels "a","c","d","g": 4 1 3 2
# $ V2: Factor w/ 4 levels "e","f","g","H": 4 1 2 3
# $ V3: int  7 1 2 3
# $ V4: int  8 4 5 6
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
 "c", "d"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("e", 
 "f", "g"), class = "factor"), V3 = 1:3, V4 = 4:6), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

v <- c('g', 'H', 7, 8)
```